# How to sort a array according to 2 value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I would like sort according to 2 value. 
first I want to sort it according to `c_gpa` value. if `c_gpa` value is equal with other value in the array then sort `t_mark` value.

Here is my array

```
$array = array(
        [0]=>array(
            "roll_number" => 1,
            "c_gpa" => 4.8,
            "t_mark"=>750
        ),
        [1] => array(
            "roll_number" => 2,
            "c_gpa" => 4.12,
            "t_mark"=>530
        ),
        [2] => array(
            "roll_number" => 3,
            "c_gpa" => 4.12,
            "t_mark"=>550
        )
```

);

I wrote below code for sort `c_gpa` value but there 2 value is same (4.12) so I want to sort it 't_mark' value these array

```
usort($array, "all_filter");
    function all_filter($a,$b) {
        return $a['c_gpa'] < $b['c_gpa'];

     }
```

my expected output is.

```
$array = array(
        [0]=>array(
            "roll_number" => 1,
            "c_gpa" => 4.8,
            "t_mark"=>750
        ),
        [1] => array(
            "roll_number" => 3,
            "c_gpa" => 4.12,
            "t_mark"=>550
        ),          
        [2] => array(
            "roll_number" => 2,
            "c_gpa" => 4.12,
            "t_mark"=>530
        )
```

);

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You mean __sort__ an array, ___filtering___ an array is something completely different

Comment: And the answer is that you modify your all_filter() to test if `$a['c_gpa'] == $b['c_gpa']` first, and if so you return `$a['t_mark'] < $b['t_mark']`

Comment: Thanks, let me check it.

Answer (score 3):

You can able to do this using array_multisort function.

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $c_gpa[$key]  = $row['c_gpa'];
    $t_mark[$key] = $row['t_mark'];
}

// Sort the data array with $c_gpa ASC, $t_mark ASC
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($c_gpa, SORT_DESC, $t_mark, SORT_ASC, $array);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

[array_multisort documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: Thanks for your help. let me check this.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `usort()`, you can use it like this, and the [demo](https://eval.in/667490)

```
   <?php
    $array = array(
            array(
                "roll_number" => 1,
                "c_gpa" => 4.8,
                "t_mark"=>750
            ),
            array(
                "roll_number" => 2,
                "c_gpa" => 4.12,
                "t_mark"=>530
            ),
            array(
                "roll_number" => 3,
                "c_gpa" => 4.12,
                "t_mark"=>550
            ));
    usort($array, function($a, $b){
      return $a['c_gpa'] > $b['c_gpa'] ? true : $a['c_gpa'] < $b['c_gpa'] ? false : $a['t_mark'] < $b['t_mark'] ? true : false;
    });
    var_dump($array);
```